# Laravel 4 - Inserting multiple records when using the hasMany relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Still finding my feet with Laravel 4 and I'm a little unsure as to why this isn't working.

In L3 I was able to insert multiple records to a table like so...

```
$comments = array(
    array('message' => 'A new comment.'),
    array('message' => 'A second comment.'),
);

$post = Post::find(1);

$post->comments()->save($comments);
```

However when I try to do similar now either the records are inserted without the foreign key, like so...

```
$comments = array(
    array('message' => 'A new comment.'),
    array('message' => 'A second comment.'),
);

$post = Post::first();

$post->comments()->insert($comments);
```

Or (and after some Googling) I try the following and get a `preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given`

```
$comments = new Comment(array(
    array('message' => 'A new comment.'),
    array('message' => 'A second comment.'),
));

$post = Post::first();

$post->comments()->save($comments);
```

As well as `...->save($comments)` I've tried `...->saveMany()` and `...->associate()` but I have the same issue as the last example.

On a side note, I do realise that I've wrapped the multidimensional array in an object but that appears to be the correct way to do this. I have tried not doing but that also fails.

I should probably point out that I'm running a seed command through artisan.

**Edit:**
This is the full `preg_match` error from the log file

`[2013-11-27 16:43:39] log.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/www/bootstrap/compiled.php:6315`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`save()` expects a single model, `saveMany()` expects an array of models, and not assoicative array of the data.

But `saveMany()` will not insert with a single query, it will actually loop trough the models and insert one by one (note: L3 also did this).

If you need to insert a larger set of records don't use the ORM, use the query builder, how [Manuel Pedrera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248107/laravel-4-inserting-multiple-records-when-using-the-hasmany-relationship#answer-20249503) wrote the first example code.

Just for the record here is how you would use `saveMany()`:

```php
$post = Post::find(1);

$comments = array(
    new Comment(array('message' => 'A new comment.')),
    new Comment(array('message' => 'A second comment.')),
);

$post->comments()->saveMany($comments);
```

Comment: saveMany() causes a lot of SQLs query being perform, may slow down performance, use insert() instead, just pass in the simple array without `new Comment`, insert will not touch the parent.

Comment: Why isn't Laravel smart enough to just `UPDATE comments SET post_id = 10 WHERE id IN (3,6,23,56)` ? Seems very trivial...

Answer (score 18):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, since it's not using Eloquent, but it should get your seeds done. You can use `DB::insert()`, like this:

```
$postId = 1;

DB::table('comments')->insert(array(
    array(
        'message' => 'A new comment.',
        'post_id' => $postId),
    array(
        'message' => 'A second comment', 
        'post_id' => $postId
    ),
));
```

---

As an alternative, you could do this using Eloquent too, but it should be done in the opposite way: setting the related model in the "childs". This is what the official docs say:

> **Associating Models (Belongs To)**
>
> When updating a belongsTo relationship, you may use the associate
>   method. This method will set the foreign key on the child model

I think it's done this way because in the database, the "child" model is the one which contains the foreign key to the "parent" (in this case, `post_id`).

The code should look like this:

```
$post = Post::find(1);

$comments = array(
    array('message' => 'A new comment.'),
    array('message' => 'A second comment.'),
);

foreach ($comments as $commentAttributes) {
    $comment = new Comment($commentAttributes);
    $comment->post()->associate($post);
    $comment->save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was hoping for a solution similar to how L3 works but for the sake of time I've used your associate example.

Comment: Glad you got it working. You can then set the question as solved by marking one of the answers as valid.